# Intent null in activity

Tags: android, android-intent

i am implementing a application for exchanges with a card. I would like to send data to same activity via Intent by clicking of a button. I found problems with the Intent managed by these overridden methods `startActivityForResult` and onResult, got from https://coderwall.com/p/bewxvw/starting-an-activity-with-result-the-clean-way, which is the implementation adapted for my usage. My Intent is null when i get it with `OnNewIntent()`.
Tx a lot for your help

```
package org.key.plugin.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



import java.io.IOException;


public class AndroidReader extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidReader";
    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    byte[] resp = {};
    private Button button = null;



    /*****
     * Manage NFC
     *
     **********/


    /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
   */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //initialize your service here

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //   finish();
            return;

        }

        if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //    mTextView.setText("NFC is disabled.");
        } else {
            //   mTextView.setText(R.string.explanation);
        }

        resolveIntent(getIntent());


        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                Log.i(TAG, "context :"+v.getContext());
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AndroidReader.class);
                byte[] data = {0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04,  0x00, 0x10, (byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x04};

                intent.putExtra("req", data);

                startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK, new SuccessResultHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Intent onResultIntent) {
                        //here you have your results data. The resultCode has already been checked against Activity.RESULT_OK
                        resp = onResultIntent.getByteArrayExtra("resp");
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResult"+resp.toString());
                    }
                });
               // transmit(null);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        /**
         * It's important, that the activity is in the foreground (resumed). Otherwise
         * an IllegalStateException is thrown.
         */
        setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
      //  mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters,
      //          mTechLists);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        /**
         * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
         */
        stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);

        super.onPause();
      //  mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
         * at the documentation.
         *
         * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }


    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Etape 0");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, "Action "+action);


// ok for Intent ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED, "action : ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED"
    // nok when i click on the button, "action : null" 


        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // status_Data.setText("Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Etape 1");
            Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            IsoDep myTag = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Etape 2");
            try {

                Log.i(TAG, "Etape 3");
                myTag.connect();
                //  status_Data.setText("Portable de contrôle");
                Log.i(TAG, "Etape 4");
                if (myTag.isConnected()) {


                    byte[] data1 = {0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04,  0x00, 0x10, (byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04};

                    byte[] responseAPDU = myTag.transceive(data1);

                }
                myTag.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //      Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
              //  showAlert(NETWORK);
            }
        }else if("org.key.plugin.android".equals(action)) {
            // status_Data.setText("Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Key Etape 1");
            Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            IsoDep myTag = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Key Etape 2");
            try {

                Log.i(TAG, "Key Etape 3");
                myTag.connect();
                //  status_Data.setText("Portable de contrôle");
                Log.i(TAG, "Key Etape 4");
                if (myTag.isConnected()) {

                    byte[] data = {};
                    //byte[] data = {0x00, 0x01};
                    //byte[] data = {0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04,  0x00, 0x10, (byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x04, 0x01, 0x25, 0x09, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
                    //return Convert.sHexToByteArray(cmd);
                    //byte[] data = intent.getExtras("string");
                    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if(extras == null) {
                        data= null;
                    } else {
                        data= extras.getByteArray("req");
                    }


                    byte[] responseAPDU = myTag.transceive(data);
                    Intent returnIntent= new Intent(AndroidReader.this, AndroidReader.class);
                    Log.i(TAG, byteArrayToSHex(responseAPDU));
                    returnIntent.putExtra("resp",responseAPDU);
                    ///have a code for each activity that you could resume to
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    finish();
                }else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Key Etape 5, deconnect");
                }
                myTag.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //      Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                //  showAlert(NETWORK);
            }
        }




    }

    /**
     * @param activity The corresponding {@link Activity} requesting the foreground dispatch.
     * @param adapter The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
     */
    public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, intent, 0);

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * @param activity The corresponding {@link Activity} requesting to stop the foreground dispatch.
     * @param adapter The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
     */
    public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
    }





}
```

Comment: Do you want send data from one activity to second activity.

Comment: What does `AndroidReader` do? It looks like that `Activity` is not returning an `Intent` before it calls `finish()`.